# What are the pros & cons of using Google CSE vs implementing dedicated search engine for a site like stackoverflow?

Tags: search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I understand that same work should not be repeated when Google CSE is already there, so what may be the reasons to should consider implementing a dedicated search engine for a public facing website similar to SO(& why probably StackOverflow did that ?). Paid version of CSE(Google site Search), already eliminates several drawbacks that forced dedicated implementation. Cost may be one reason to not choose Google CSE, but what are other reasons ?

Another thing I want to ask is my site is similar kind as StackOverflow, so when Google indexes its content every now & then, won't that overload my database servers with lots of queries may be when there is peak traffic time?

I look forward to use Google Custom search API but I need to clarify whether the 1000 paid queries that I get for 5$ are valid only for 1 day or they get adjusted to extra queries(beyond free ones) on the next day & so on. Can anyone clarify on this too?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the content of your site, the frequency of the updates, and the kind of search you want to provide.

For example, with StackOverflow, there'd probably be no way to search for questions of an individual user through Google, but it can be done with an internal search engine easily.

Similarly, Google can outdate their API at any time; in fact, if past experience is any indication, Google has already done so with their Google Web Search API, where a lot of non-profits that had projects based on such API were left on the street with no Google options for continuation of their services (paying 100 USD/year for only 20'000 search queries per year, may be fine for a posh blog indeed, but greatly limits what you can actually use the search API for).

On the other hand, you probably already want to have Google index all of your pages, to get the organic search traffic, so Google CSE would probably use rather minimal resources of your server, compared to having a complete in-house search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Google Site Search is gone, the best search tool alternative for all the loyal Google fans is Google Custom Search (CSE)

Some of the features of Google Custom Search that I loved the most, were :-

Its free (with ads)
Ability to monetise those ads with your AdSense Account
Tons of Customization options, including removing the Google branding,
Ability to link it with Google Analytics account, for highly comprehensive analytical report,
Powerful auto correct feature to understand the real intention behind the typos,
Cons : Lacks customer Support…
Read More: https://www.techrbun.com/2019/05/google-custom-search-features.html